# How to display the result of a BlockMatrix multiplication in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

This sounds like a simple question, but I am not able to figure out how to display the contents of a pyspark BlockMatrix to the console. What methods should I call on it to actually see my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `toLocalMatrix()`. I used an example matrix from the [Spark MLLib Python API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix) to illustrate:

```
mat = mat1.toLocalMatrix()

# which returns a DenseMatrix
# DenseMatrix(6, 2, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0], 0)

# and could be further converted to a numpy array using `.toArray()`:
np_mat = mat.toArray()
# array([[ 1.,  4.],
#        [ 2.,  5.],
#        [ 3.,  6.],
#        [ 7., 10.],
#        [ 8., 11.],
#        [ 9., 12.]])
```

Comment: Thanks! All that was needed was to print(mat) to display the local matrix. It took me another few minutes to realize this object is printable.